# Android KeyboardView throws Nullpointer

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want to make my own keyboard.

I have the following code

When I ran the code, it throws NullPointerException.

---

My `RKeyboardView` that extends `KeyboardView`

```
package com.glenn.droid; // MY package

import android.content.Context;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class RKeyboardView extends KeyboardView {

    public RKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

My main activity

```
MobileActivity.java

public class MobileActivity extends ListActivity  {

    private RKeyboardView r;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        r = (RKeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.rKeyboardView1);
        r.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(this,R.xml.qwerty));

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

What should I do? Please help me.

Comment: What null pointer exception? It doesn't just happen, some particular object is incorrectly set to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the line

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

to directly after

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

The findViewById() method searches the tree of Views (the View hierarchy) in your activity for one with the specified id, and returns that View object. If you have not called setContentView before you call findViewById(), then the particular View object has neither been created nor added to the View hierarchy.